# ExtJS store filter is being sent not in full

Tags: extjs, filter, proxy, store

I've a store syncronized with remote db model. I need to apply remote filtering. Problem is that if i set a filter in config options the filter is being sent (on load or on sync) but not fully.
**Store**:

```
var RegularItemsStore=Ext.create("appMain.Store.UniversalStore",{
     model: 'OrderModel',
     modelName:'Order2',  
     autoSync: true, 
     filters:  [{ "property" : "storeId", "value": 0 , "type": "numeric",  "operator": "="}, 
});
```

in Http ajax request this filter is passed with **ONLY** `"property" : "storeId", "value": 0`, the `"type": "numeric",  "operator": "="` are missed; in **web-dev tools**:

```
Query String Parameters 
    r:backend/index
    Table:Order2
    log:0 
    ...
    filter:[{"property":"storeId","value":0}]
```

while if i set filter on the proxy pertaining to store, the filter is passed to server unchanged (in right way):
**Proxy config**:

```
this.proxy =         
{  
    url:  "index.php?r=backend/index&Table=" + this.modelName + this.params,
    reader: { 
         root: "result.data",
         totalProperty: "result.count",     
         type: "json",
         metaProperty: 'myMetaData', // config for metaData:  
    }, 
    actionMethods: {
          read: 'GET', update: 'POST'
    },   
    ...
};
```

and **filter applying**:

```
Ext.each(ItemStoreArray, function(store){
   var filter = [ { property: 'contractorId', value: ContractorSelectedId ,  operator: '=', type: 'numeric' }, { property: 'userId', value: UserId ,  operator: '=', type: 'numeric' }];  
   store.getProxy().setExtraParam('filter' , Ext.JSON.encode(filter) ); 
   store.load();        //console.dir(store);               
});
```

How to resolve it? Should i set a permanent filter on proxy in the store init, how?

## Update

As followed Alexander's recommendation i've overriden the proxy's config parameter that solved the issue:

```
encodeFilters: function(filters) {
     var min = [],
     length = filters.length,
     i = 0;

     for (; i < length; i++) {
        min[i] = {
             property: filters[i].property,
             value   : filters[i].value,
             operator   : filters[i].operator, // added
             type   : filters[i].type, // added
         };
     }
     return this.applyEncoding(min);
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `encodeFilters: function(filters)` in the proxy you use.

For the default implementation have a look at src/data/proxy/Server.js.

Comment: may i ask you, of where there might be this file located; i've search for the folders and found nothing...Here is the shot of my extjs dir: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2NIZgbwy5TmQzloVGVueDhmRmM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: it is in the Ext source code you can download from their site. I don't know where it is on your hard drive, but they even have it in the web: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/Server.html#Ext-data-proxy-Server-method-encodeFilters